# How do I get the last value for each calendar month using flux?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I have a few sensors that every 1st day of the month they reset the value. I have been using the last value with success but didnt find a way to get the max/last value in a given calendar month. For each calendar month, for each sensor I mean. I am a beginner working with flux.

I tried the agreggate with 1 month, but looks like it is not going to the last day of each month, and I wanted to have for each month.

I have several sensors that are cumulative per month, but on the first measurement of the month they go to zero. I wanted to have a way to visualise for each past month what the measurement was last, for all the sensors so I can put in grafana and see each month how it was the consumption.

This is my query, which returns the last value for each of the 20 sensors:

```
from(bucket: "home")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["friendly_name"] =~ /1MON$/ and r["friendly_name"] !~ /^Main/)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "kWh")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] !~ /2$/)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a aggregateWindow for month with function last. Something like this:

```
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: last, createEmpty: true)
```

Maybe fn: max would also work.